# Ошибка Property assignment expected

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Всем привет.
Есть вот такая строка кода. В строке пытаюсь изменить свойство ordersCount у конкретного элемента массива.
VS Code выдает ошибку Property assignment expected, подчеркивая suppliers. Почему? Что не так?

```
    Service.findOneAndUpdate(
     {},
     { $set: { `suppliers.${supplierIndex}.ordersCount`: ordersCount + 1 }},
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Service.findOneAndUpdate(
     {},
     { $set: { [`suppliers.${supplierIndex}.ordersCount`]: ordersCount + 1 }},
    )
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/871763)

Comment: Ответ на вопрос исчерпывающий. Если присмотреться, в ответе можно заметить квадратные скобки, которые были пропущены в вопросе.